# An unexpected error with the following message occurred: For input string: ""

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I'm getting the following error from ORDS when an AJAX process is executed within a page in APEX:

```
An unexpected error with the following message occurred: For input string: ""
```

The code I was using for printing the response to the HTTP stream was:

```sql
DECLARE
    L_HTTP_STATUS NUMBER;
    L_HTTP_REASON_PHRASE VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    -- ...
    APEX_JSON.INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(
        P_HTTP_HEADER => FALSE,
        P_INDENT => 4
    );
    OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER(
        CCONTENT_TYPE => 'application/json',
        BCLOSE_HEADER => FALSE,
        CCHARSET => NULL
    );
    OWA_UTIL.STATUS_LINE(
        NSTATUS => L_HTTP_STATUS,
        CREASON => L_HTTP_REASON_PHRASE,
        BCLOSE_HEADER => TRUE
    );
    APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT();
    -- ...
    APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT();
END;
```

Although nothing seems wrong with it I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error was that the `L_HTTP_STATUS` variable was never being set, therefore was `NULL`, and ORDS doesn't like `NULL` status headers, although I wonder why is it that `OWA_UTIL.STATUS_LINE` allows `NULL` in the first place. Anyway hopefully it helps someone who is having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me I solved it by reinstall ORDS
using the command

```
c:\apex\ords\bin> ORDS install
```

and select choice 2 create or update database pool
then choice 1 basic host name and continue the defaults choices
after that ORDS started with no errors